# How to prevent fixed layout to break on mobile if the user zooms [Pictures included]?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

SO yeah, I have one vertical header on my website that I want to show to all my users who are in landscape mode. This header is fixed in place and the user can scroll the header or the content. My probleem is that when ever the user zooms in they layout breaks because the header stays in his old place, is there anyway to fix this?
**Edit:**

```
header
  flex: 0 0 auto
  width: 15rem

.headerContainer
  height: 100%
  overflow-y: scroll
  width: 15rem
  padding-bottom: 1.25rem
  position: fixed
```

**Edit:**
Medium has what I want/need https://medium.com/
[image]

[image]

Comment: This likely has to do with max-width within the containing div.  The elements (and especially images) contained within your vertical  header div should have something like max-width:100% (or 90% to give a bit of room).

Comment: OR, you could change up the css by using a media query for when the browser screen goes below a certain width.  Just search for "css media query" to learn how, and experiment with the look and feel you want for various screen sizes.

Comment: No, that is not it. It is because of possition Fixed.